# Get bitmap of browser window

Tags: c++, google-chrome, firefox

Does anyone know how to get a the bitmap of a Mac and Windwos browser window? I want to capture images from Chrome or FireFox as they are rendered and pass them into a C++ based plug-in.

I've looked into using a Chrome extension, but it's not practical.

Willing to do a Mac and Windows native app.

Comment: if extensions aren't being considered, remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the windows API you can grab screenshots fairly easy.

```
// get the device context of the screen
HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);     
// and a device context to put it in
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

int width = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

// maybe worth checking these are positive values
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);

// get a new bitmap
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

// clean up
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
// now your image is held in hBitmap. You can save it or do whatever with it
```

Im not sure about the exact area of the browser tho, or how to solve it for Mac. If nothing else, its a start.